# setting a function argument default value as a variable value at the time of creation of the function

Tags: r, function

Can I create a function with the default value of an argument set to the value of a variable at the time of creation?

```
Something like,
a=1
fn = function(arg1 = a) {
  print (arg1+1)
}
```

`fn` would show

```
function(arg1 = 1) {
  print (arg1+1)
}
```

Comment: I would use bquote or substitute and then eval the expression.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. Could you elaborate on how it works... I figured out how to do it but I am not sure I fully understand how it works...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the global options in R:

```
fn <- function(arg1 = getOption("arg1", 1)) {
     print(arg1 + 1)
}

fn() # returns 2
options(arg1 = 5)
fn() # returns 6
fn(2) # returns 3
options(arg1 = NULL)
fn() # returns 2 again
```

I think the above solution is cleaner compared to using a global variable in .GlobalEnv, but here is also how you can do it with a global variable in .GlobalEnv:

```
fn2 <- function(arg1 = if( is.null(.GlobalEnv[["a"]]) ) 1 else .GlobalEnv[["a"]]) {
  print(arg1+1)
}

fn2() # this returns an empty vector
a <- 5
fn2() # this returns 6
```

Comment: Thank you. It could be a way around.

Answer (score 1):

Helped by help for `bquote` function. Here is what I found working for me.

It does not look straight forward to me but it works.

```
a=1
fn <- eval(bquote( function(arg1 = .(a)) {
    print (arg1+1)
} ))
fn
fn(3)
```

`eval(bquote())` and `.(a)` are the point.

I found the hows but I don't think I fully understood it. 
So anyone can help me understand how it works, I will be glad to take it as an answer.

Comment: It's basic computing on the language. You construct an expression and then evaluate it. This ensures that the default function parameter is a value and not a symbol.